# Simulate mouse move in 3D games?

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, mouse

Hi
I made a human computer interface to control mouse using fingers using C++ and OpenCV in CodeBlocks IDE
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q5aXTg0pVE
I want to use this in a 3D game like medal of honor

First I used SetCursorPos(x,y) it did not work so I switched to SendInput and mouse_event.
They did work with a bug the character began pointing in all random directions and changing directions on its own.

Should I use directinput as the game uses directx.
If so how?
I have tried many tutorials but all speak about how to get data from mouse but not how to insert into the mouse stream
I used both absolute and relative positioning but both failed the character is behaving odd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your code, this answer is a bit of a long shot, but here goes.

`SendInput` should work, but I think the game is interfering by using `SetCursorPos` itself. Many games reset the cursor to the centre of the screen each frame, so it doesn't hit the edge by accident.

Try using `SendInput` with relative mouse motion, so *without* the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag in the [`MOUSEINPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646273%28VS.85%29.aspx) struct.

Comment: Hi Thomas Thanx a ton your idea worked to some extent after removing MOUSEEVENT_ABSOULUTE flag charecter stopped moving randomly but the problem now is the pointer is always sitting at the extreme (x,y) position whatever maybe the values of X and Y :-(

Comment: Hi Thanx a ton I corrected my code the bug was accidental multiplication tats it You really helped me Thanks once more